# Missing argument

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

so I'am working on a school project where we need to build a site to rent movies and im kinda stuck.

Im getting the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE idFilm = NULL)' at line 1' in /home/ubuntu/workspace/classes/video.php on line 334
>
> ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE idFilm = NULL)' at line 1 in /home/ubuntu/workspace/classes/video.php on line 334

The idea is that you can create a new movie and add one or more genres. Im failing on connecting the genres to the movies.

So my code is:

```
<?php
    include('security.php');
        $genre = $video->getAllGenre();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $error = "";
        //var_dump($_POST);
        $target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/covers/';
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $fileName = $video->generateCoverName() .'.'. end($temp);
        $target_file =  $target_dir . $fileName;
        //echo('Target file: '.$target_file);
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check == false) {
            $error = "Bestand is geen foto.";
        }
        if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 50000000) {
            $error = "Sorry, bestand is te groot.";
        }
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
           && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
            $error = "Sorry, alleen jpg, png, jpeg en gif zijn toegestaan.";
        }
        if (!$error) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                //echo "The file ". $fileName. " has been uploaded.";
                $video->genreToFilm($_POST['idFilm'], $_POST['idGenre']);
                $video->newVideo($_POST['titel'], $_POST['aantal'], $fileName, $_POST['omschrijving'], $_POST['prijs']);
            } else {
                echo("Sorry, er was een probleem met het uploaden van uw bestand.");
            }
        } else {
            print('<div class="alert alert-info fade-out">'.$error.'</div>');
        }

    }
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 loginborder">
        <form role="form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h2 class="loginhead">Film toevoegen</h2>
            <hr>
               <div class="registrationform">
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                        <p>Titel:</p>
                        <input type="text" name="titel" id="titel" class="form-control input-lg" required  value="<?php if(isset($error)){ print($_POST['titel']); } ?>" tabindex="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                        <p>Upload een coverfoto:</p>
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class="omschrijving form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                        <p>Omschrijving:</p>
                        <textarea style="resize: none;" name="omschrijving" rows="12" cols="50" placeholder="Omschrijving van de film..." required class="form-control"><?php  if(isset($error)){ print($_POST['omschrijving']); }?></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <p>Aantal:</p>
                        <input type="number" name="aantal" id="aantal" class="form-control input-lg" min="0" max="1000" step="1" required value="<?php if(isset($error)){ print($_POST['aantal']); } ?>" tabindex="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <p>Prijs:</p>
                        <input type="number" name="prijs" id="prijs" class="form-control input-lg" min="0" max="9999.99" step="0.01" required value="<?php if(isset($error)){ print($_POST['aantal']); } ?>" tabindex="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                        <p>Genre 1:</p>
                        <select name="genre1" class="form-control input-lg">
                            <?php foreach ($genre as $gen) {
                                print(
                                      '<option value='.$gen['idGenre'].'>'.$gen['genre'].'</option>');
                            } ?>
                        </select> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                        <p>Genre 2:</p>
                        <select name="genre2" class="form-control input-lg">
                            <?php foreach ($genre as $gen) {
                                print('<option value='.$gen['idGenre'].'>'.$gen['genre'].'</option>');
                            } ?>
                        </select> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                        <p>Genre 3:</p>
                        <select name="genre3" class="form-control input-lg">
                            <?php foreach ($genre as $gen) {
                                print('<option value='.$gen['idGenre'].'>'.$gen['genre'].'</option>');
                            } ?>
                        </select> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                        <p>Acteur 1:</p>
                        <input type="text" name="acteurs" id="acteur1" class="form-control input-lg" min="0" max="1000" step="1" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ print($_POST['acteurs']); } ?>" tabindex="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                        <p>Acteur 2:</p>
                        <input type="text" name="acteur2" id="acteur2" class="form-control input-lg" min="0" max="1000" step="1" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ print($_POST['acteurs']); } ?>" tabindex="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                        <p>Acteur 3:</p>
                        <input type="text" name="acteur3" id="acteur3" class="form-control input-lg" min="0" max="1000" step="1" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ print($_POST['acteurs']); } ?>" tabindex="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                        <p>Acteur 4:</p>
                        <input type="text" name="acteur4" id="acteur4" class="form-control input-lg" min="0" max="1000" step="1" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ print($_POST['acteurs']); } ?>" tabindex="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                        <p>Acteur 5:</p>
                        <input type="text" name="acteur5" id="acteur5" class="form-control input-lg" min="0" max="1000" step="1" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ print($_POST['acteurs']); } ?>" tabindex="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="submitVideoToevoegen col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verstuur" class="btn btn-lg " tabindex="5">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the code of the class is:

```
    public function genreToFilm($idFilm, $idGenre){
        try{
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('INSERT INTO FilmGenre 
                                        VALUES(:idFilm, :idGenre WHERE idFilm = :idFilm)');
            if($stmt->execute(array(':idGenre' => $idGenre,
                                    ':idFilm' => $idFilm))){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } catch (PDOExeption $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your idFilm value is null so not set

Comment: There is no `INSERT INTO..WHERE`. Do you mean to run an `UPDATE` query instead? Also the parenthesis around that is wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to create a NEW row, or AMEND an existing row

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have a row with all the genres and a row with all the movies. Im trying to insert the id of the genres and the id of the movie together in a intermediate table.

Comment: Right EVERYONE... OP is creating a link table and will need an INSERT to do that. ___Alll cleared up___ thanks Kenneth

Comment: So look at @PaulaHenrique answer, to correct the syntax of an INSERT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You re missing the columns destination here. I'm not adept of the Pdo method, but I don't think the where clause could be inside the values statement, either.

```
$this->_db->prepare('INSERT INTO FilmGenre VALUES(:idFilm, :idGenre WHERE idFilm = :
```

You should do this:

```
$this->_db->prepare('INSERT INTO FilmGenre (idFilmColumn, idGenreColumn ) VALUES(:idFilm, :idGenreColumn)') ;
```

Comment: OP does not want an insert statement. Probably an Update statement will do.

Comment: Even if its supposed to be an `INSERT` query, you don't always need to specify the columns - if you take a look at the manual, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: @Qirel Looks to me like he is trying to create a simple link table row. So maybe it is supposed to be an insert

Comment: Ain't that the big question here, @Riggs ;-) Insert or update, in any case, OP is using the wrong syntax.

Comment: @Akintunde, according to PHP manual, inserts are allowed in prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepared-statements.php. Thank you.

Comment: OP probably needs an Update statement. Read my comment properly

Comment: @PauloHenrique I dont think he was saying you cannot do an insert. He was saying he thinks an update would do the job. I dont personally think that is right. But the question is a little ambiguous

Comment: that's  right, now a I understand that WHERE inside INSERT statement. @Kenneth, you have to check whether the user is updating the record or inserting a new one. If this is just about updating, you should then change to an UPDATE statement, as referred above. You should consider using an ORM, so you don't bother too much on writing queries and logic for this: http://propelorm.org/ (is my preferred one)